# Magento 2 : Override the Shipping Method Managment Model

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3.4

I need to override the **shippingmethodmagament.php** file which is in the **model** file in the magento this path `vendor\magento\module-quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement.php`

but the interfaces is applied in this file and i have try with the preference but its not properly work

I need to override this function inside the my custom module model please help me out to override this core function
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create Plugin for it instead of override

`app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagementInterface">
          <plugin name="allowEmptyQuotes" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Quote\ShippingMethodManagement\Plugin" sortOrder="1"/>
      </type>
</config>
```

`app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Quote/ShippingMethodManagement/Plugin.php`
<?php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Quote\ShippingMethodManagement;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository;

class Plugin
{
      /**
       * Quote repository.
       *
       * @var QuoteRepository
       */
      protected $quoteRepository;

      /**
       * Shipping method converter
       *
       * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter
       */
      protected $converter;

      /**
       * @param QuoteRepository $quoteRepository Quote repository.
       */
      public function __construct(
          QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
          ShippingMethodConverter $converter
      ) {
          $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
          $this->converter = $converter;
      }

      /**
       * Allow empty quote for calculating the shipping methods / costs
       *
       * Plugin for: @see \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement::estimateByAddress
       *
       * @param $subject
       * @param $result
       */
      public function aroundEstimateByAddress(
          \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement $subject,
          \Closure $proceed,
          $cartId,
          \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\EstimateAddressInterface $address
      ) {
            // Your code
      }
}
```

Comment: opps..I found you need to override private function so above code not work for you. I will post another answer soon

Comment: yes this is private function we cannot use the plugin method for it. I am waiting for your reply